# window.parent.location.href IE9 Bug?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, window.location, window.parent

Scenario:

1. domain1.com hosts an iFrame of domain2.com.
2. domain2.com is using javascript to trigger dynamic links that need
   to route to the parent window.
3. The links are all relative paths.
4. Clicking on /linkA.html (in iframe on domain2.com) routes the parent to
   domain1.com/linkA.html.

   var _generic = "/linkA.html";

   ```
       $("#canvas").each( function () {
           $(this).children("a").attr("href",_generic);
           $(this).click( function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               window.parent.location.href = _generic;
           } );
       } );
   ```

---

Changing the links to absolute (domain2.com/linkA.html) solves the functional problem.

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the browser to resolve the entire url when setting relative paths, it first needs to read the current href, and this is blocked by the SOP.

But I am pretty sure that if you use `parent.location` instead of `parent.location.href`, then this will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `window.opener.location` instead of `window.parent.location`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a difference in IE9 vs. IE8, FireFox, and Webkit. Consider the following code:

Parent source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>iframe test page</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>Parent window</h1>
    <iframe src="//domain2/iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe source (on separate domain):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>iframe content</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>iframe content</h1>
    <script>function redirect() { window.parent.location = "/new-href"; } </script>
    <a href="javascript:redirect()">Redirect the parent window please</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If the main page is opened in IE8 (or IE9 set to run in IE8 mode or Chrome 23 or FF16) clicking the link results in navigating to //(iframe domain)/new-href whereas in IE9 it goes to //(original parent domain)/new-href

I am still investigating how to work around this issue and will update this if/when I have more information.

**UPDATE: Setting the target="_top" attribute for iframe links works around this problem.**

Updated iframe source (on separate domain):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>iframe content</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>iframe content</h1>
    <a href="/new-href" target="_top">Redirect the parent window please</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking the link in this updated iframe code will redirect the parent (entire) window to //(iframe domain)/new-href in both IE8 & IE9 (and, as far as I know, all browsers as well). That is what you want to do, right?

e.g. If you want to make all  tags in an iframe cause the top/main/parent window to navigate somewhere rather than the iframe navigating somewhere then use something like this:

```
$("iframe a").attr("target", "_top");
```

See also [target attribute documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: I tried "window.opener.location" in IE9 and got a console error (unable to set value of the property 'location': object is null or undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash implicit folder in the URL works in Moz. browsers, but with explorer, links from the same folder don not put the forward slash.
It's simply X-browser syntax.
You may have done better puting ./ (dot forward slash with explorer but the proper way is no slash preceding the filename for a same folder URL).